# how to catch scroll event caused by hash bang anchor link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, anchor

I am just wondering if there's a better way to approach this

So, say you have `jump to` link using anchor tag:

`www.example.com/#about`

opening that link will make browser natively auto-scroll to the section with

`<div id="about"></div>`

now, I want to catch this `scroll` event, so that I can add more `offset` on how much scroll the browser should use.

The reason for this is because I have a `fixed` navigation menu that consumes `120px` of the browser.

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to intercept this behaviour directly i.e. there is no user accessible event associated with it. Instead `window.location.hash` is made available to you. You can find the associated element and jump to it once the page has loaded.

e.g. something like:

```
function jumpToElement(element, offset) {
  if (!offset) offset = 0;
  var verticalPos = element.offsetHeight;
  window.scrollTo(0, verticalPos + offset);
}
function jumpToHash(offset) {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  // Do nothing if no hash exists
  if (typeof hash !== 'string' || !hash.length) return;
  var targetElement = document.querySelector(hash);
  // Do nothing if targetElement doesn't exist
  if (!targetElement) return;
  jumpToHash(targetElement, offset);
});
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
  jumpToHash(-120); // with 120px
} else {
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", jumpToHash);
}
```

Comment: marked as answer because its true, **there is no way to intercept this behaviour directly**

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `scroll()` Method. The scroll event occurs when the user scrolls in the specified element and it works for all scrollable elements and the window object (browser window). The `scroll()` method triggers the scroll event, or attaches a function to run when a scroll event occurs.

Trigger the scroll event for the selected elements:

```
$(selector).scroll()
```

Attach a function to the scroll event:

```
$(selector).scroll(function)
```

Example:

```js
var $titlebar = $( '.titlebar' ),
    fixedPosition = function() {
      var pos1 = $titlebar.offset().top,
          winTop = $( window ).scrollTop();
          $( window ).scrollTop( winTop + 1 );
          var pos2 = $titlebar.offset().top;
          $( window ).scrollTop( winTop );
          return ( pos1 != pos2 )
    }(),
    titlebarHeight = fixedPosition ? $titlebar.outerHeight() : 0,
    $menu = $( '.nav a' );
        
$( '.nav a' ).click( function( e ) {
  var $target = $( this.hash );

  e.preventDefault();

  if ( !$( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
            $( 'html, body' ).stop( true, false ).animate( {
                'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - titlebarHeight
            }, 800 );
        }
    } );

$( window ).on( 'scroll', function() {
  didScroll = true
} );

setInterval( function() {
  if ( didScroll ) {
    didScroll = false;

    var scrollPos = $( document ).scrollTop(),
        windowHeight = ( $( window ).height() - titlebarHeight ) / 2;

        if ( fixedPosition ) {
          $menu.each( function( index ) {
            var $page = $( this.hash );

            if ( $page.position().top <= scrollPos + titlebarHeight + windowHeight ) {
              $( '.nav a.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
              $menu.eq( index ).addClass( 'active' )
            }
          });
        }
  }
}, 150 );
```

```css
html,
body,
.contents,
.contents div {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%
}
.titlebar {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none
}
.nav li {
  display: inline
}
.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
     -moz-transition-duration: .2s;
       -o-transition-duration: .2s;
          transition-duration: .2s
}
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
.nav a.active,
.nav a.active:hover{
    color: #69452d;
    background-color: #e1ba89;
    cursor: default
}
#home {
  padding: 4em 1em 1em;
  background-color: #b6946b
}
#features {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #e1ba89
}
#buy {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #ddd
}
#contact {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="titlebar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li
    ><li><a href="#features">Features</a></li
    ><li><a href="#buy">Buy</a></li
    ><li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="contents">
  <div id="home">Home</div>
  <div id="features">Features</div>
  <div id="buy">Buy</div>
  <div id="contact">Contact Us</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JS for that, you can just add `scroll-margin-top: 120px` to that element in CSS.

Comment: Excellent answer! It works.